# Excluding a single string from a text

Tags: regex

I wanted to exclude the string "exit" in the text below with Regex.

```
cnt number: 1452365877

cnt exit no : 145263888

CCS No : BBSD145222
```

It should become like this:

```
cnt number: 1452365877

cnt  no : 145263888

CCS No : BBSD145222
```

So, how can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly do mention which language you are looking.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer would depend on the tool/language you are using, but a general approach would be to find `\bexit\b`, and then just replace with empty string.  See the demo link below for an example.

### Demo

Note that we place word boundaries (`\b`) around the word `exit`, to avoid unwanted possible matches such as `exits` or `Brexit`.

**Edit:**

If you want to highlight all words except for `exit`, then try using this pattern:

```
\b(?!exit\b)\S+\b
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you. As I explained later in this page, your code only displays exit string. but I want to display anything except exit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not for any programming languages. There is an automation software called VisualCron and it uses Regex to match everything. It is something like this:

```
  {REGEX(Match|{TRIGGER(Active|LastTrigger|Mail.Result.Mail.BodyText)}|\b[0-9]{9})}
```

I want the above regex code to display everything from an Email body text except "exit".